# Alter table not adding foreign key MYSQL

Tags: mysql

When I execute the below, it looks like it sets up a regular KEY, not a foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE `dev1_IMGStoreTmpComponents`
ADD CONSTRAINT `con_fk_templates`
FOREIGN KEY `fk_templates`(`templateId`)
REFERENCES `dev1_IMGStoreTemplates`(`templateId`)
```

SQL runs successfully.

then I run this:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `dev1_IMGStoreTmpComponents`;

 CREATE TABLE `dev1_IMGStoreTmpComponents` (
 `componentId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
 `description` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `templateId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `type` char(3) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
 `layer` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `posx` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `posy` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `width` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `height` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `settings` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,
 PRIMARY KEY (`componentId`),
 UNIQUE KEY `componentId` (`componentId`,`templateId`),
 KEY `con_fk_templates` (`templateId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci COMMENT='Template Components'
```

Why don't I see the CONSTRAINT in the Create table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql: adding foreign key does not give warning/error on MyISAM tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573528/mysql-adding-foreign-key-does-not-give-warning-error-on-myisam-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyISAM storage engine doesn't support foreign key constraints.

```
ENGINE=MYISAM
```

InnoDB storage engine supports referential integrity constraints. (Both the referencing table and referenced table need to be defined with InnoDB storage engine.)

```
ENGINE=INNODB
```

---

MySQL does accept the foreign key constraint syntax for a MyISAM table, but MySQL disregards the foreign key. The most likely reason that the syntax is accepted is to make migration of DDL from other databases easier.

Comment: Ah, ok. that makes sense.  Now I can stop banging my head on this.  Thanks!